# Resize the header and content div dimensions respond when the window size changes but maintain right sidebar dimensions

Tags: css, html, flexbox

I am trying to use a flexbox approach to create a layout that will resize the header width and content dimensions when a window is resized, but maintain the sidebar dimensions.

I found the following example from this [Flexbox Approach](http://www.mzan.com/article/90178-make-a-div-fill-the-height-of-the-remaining-screen-space.shtml) to get me started, and it works as desired for the content div itself. But after looking it over, I'm unsure how to make it work as described with a fixed width, 100% height sidebar.

CSS from example:

```
<style>
 html, body { 
   height: 100%; 
   margin: 0 
  } 
 .box { 
   display: flex; 
   flex-flow: column; 
   height: 100%; 
  } 
 .box .row { 
   border: 1px dotted grey; 
  } 
 .box .row.header { 
   flex: 0 1 auto; /* The above is shorthand for: flex-grow: 0, flex-shrink: 1, flex-basis: auto */ } 
 .box .row.content { 
   flex: 1 1 auto; 
  } 
 .box .row.footer { 
   flex: 0 1 40px; 
  }
  </style>
```

HTML from example:

```
  <div class="row header"> 
    <p><b>header</b> <br /> <br />(sized to content)</p> 
  </div> <div class="row content">
    <p> <b>content</b> (fills remaining space) </p> 
  </div> 
  <div class="row footer"> 
    <p><b>footer</b> (fixed height)</p> 
  </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Consider simplifying this question and posting enough code to reproduce the problem. A live demo may also help (e.g., jsfiddle.net, codepen.io).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.. I guess I wasn't sure how to get started with the layout I wanted, but I found this to help me figure it out: http://codepen.io/JosephSilber/pen/HqgAz

Answer (score 0):

The following codepen example gave me the information I needed to get my layout working:

http://codepen.io/JosephSilber/pen/HqgAz

CSS:

```
.header {
  height: 50px;
}

.body {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;

  display: flex;
}

.sidebar {
  width: 140px;
}

.main {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.content {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  overflow: auto;
}

.box {
  min-height: -webkit-min-content;
  display: flex;
}

.column {
  padding: 20px;
  border-right: 1px solid #999;
}

.column > div {
  height: 2000px;
  background: red;
}

.column:nth-child(2) > div {
   height: auto;
}

/* All of these are just for this demo's design. */

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.header {
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  background: #444;
}

.sidebar {
  background: #666;
  padding: 4px 20px;
  color: #fff;
}

.page-header {
  padding: 6px 20px;
  background: #004141;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: .8em;
}

.content {
  background: #ddd;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="header">Main header</div>

<div class="body">
```

> Move this: `<div class="sidebar">Sidebar</div>`

```
    <div class="main">

        <div class="page-header">Page Header. Content columns are below.</div>

        <div class="content">

            <div class="box">
              <div class="column">
                  <div>Column 1</div>
              </div>
              <div class="column">
                  <div>Column 1</div>
              </div>
              <div class="column">
                  <div>Column 1</div>
              </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

> To here: `<div class="sidebar">Sidebar</div>`

```
</div>
```

To get the sidebar on the right side, I simply moved `<div class="sidebar">Sidebar</div>`to just above the closing div tag for the .body class.